# Differentiate between a row modification and add?

Tags: oracle

Any recommendations into how one can figure out which rows were solely modified from an existing row (edit) and which one were solely inserted?

I know minus can extract any rows that were modified in any way (add/delete/edit), but right now I feel the only way to differentiate an "edit" among these 3 is to compare "hard values" shared between corresponding records and detect the column change...

Take below for example:

```
Table GarageBefore
__________________________
|Make |Color |VIN |Driver |  
|AUDI |GRAY  |650 |SMITH  |
|BMW  |SILV  |808 |JOHNS  |
|BMW  |GREE  |754 |CARRO  |
|CHEV |WHIT  |532 |JONES  |
|_________________________|

Table GarageAfter
__________________________
|Make |Color |VIN |Driver |  
|AUDI |GRAY  |650 |SMITH  |
|BMW  |SILV  |303 |JOHNS  |
|BMW  |GREE  |754 |CARRO  |
|BUIC |BLAC  |400 |JAMES  |
|CHEV |WHIT  |532 |JONES  |
|_________________________|


Desired Result

(Modified Existing Rows?)
|BMW  |SILV  |303 |JOHNS  |


(Added Rows?)
|BUIC |BLAC  |400 |JAMES  |
```

Comment: Without some sort of immutable key, you can't.  In this example, I'd expect that to be `vin`.  A vehicle's VIN is never going to change, it's a unique, immutable natural key.  But that's the one value that did change.  You can guess by looking to see how many columns match, potentially assigning different priorities to different columns (i.e. a match on `color` is less definitive than a match on `make` which is less definitive than a match on `driver`).  But that's going to be probabilistic and highly data dependent.

Comment: Use triggers - or Oracle also have FGA (Fine Grained Auditing) which may do what you want - AFAIK, it's EE (Enterprise Edition).

Answer (score 1):

From the datasets you posted, no. You could add a column "modified" which contains a flag that tells you whether the row was modified or not. That column could be maintained via a trigger on the table, or, in my opinion better, you could encapsulate inserts/updates to that table in a stored procedure and have the procedure maintain that column.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table garage
(
  make varchar2(10),
  color varchar2(10),
  vin number,
  driver varchar2(10)
);

insert into garage values ('AUDI', 'GRAY', 650, 'SMITH');
insert into garage values ('BMW', 'SILV', 808, 'JOHNS');
insert into garage values ('BMW', 'GREE', 754, 'CARRO');
insert into garage values ('CHEV', 'WHIT', 532, 'JONES');
commit;
```

Let's query the time here:

```
select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
-------------------
2015-08-13 22:52:30
```

Do some modifications:

```
update garage set vin = 303 where vin = 808;
insert into garage values ('BUIC', 'BLAC', 400, 'JAMES');
commit;
```

Let's query the time again:

```
select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
-------------------
2015-08-13 22:52:42
```

Now let's use [Flashback Version Query](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_flashback.htm#i1019938) and find the modifications in that time period:

```
select
  garage.*,
  garage.rowid,
  versions_starttime as starttime,
  versions_operation as operation
from garage versions between timestamp 
timestamp'2015-08-13 22:52:30' and timestamp'2015-08-13 22:52:42'
where versions_operation is not null;

MAKE       COLOR       VIN DRIVER     ROWID              STARTTIME             OPERATION
---------- ---------- ---- ---------- ------------------ --------------------- ----------
BUIC       BLAC        400 JAMES      AAAWKFAAEAAAAJcAAE 13-AUG-15 10.52.36 PM I
BMW        SILV        303 JOHNS      AAAWKFAAEAAAAJcAAB 13-AUG-15 10.52.36 PM U
```

Here you can see BMW, SILV row was updated (`U` in column `OPERATION`), and BUIC, BLAC row was inserted (`I` in column `OPERATION`).

(Note that a `ROWID` may change.)